# How to monitor TCP data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tcp, cfnetwork

How to monitor TCP data in iOS,and we can use NSURLProtocol monitor HTTP data,How about TCP，I want monitor TCP data such as data flow，server host ，and network state

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, I'm pretty sure you can't, or at least not beyond the bounds of your own app.  And I doubt there's a way you could do it even for your own app's traffic.

If you're doing this strictly for internal purposes, you can do so on a router (or use your Mac as a router, and do so by monitoring the bridge interface).

Alternatively, with permission from Apple (this requires a special entitlement), you could create a Network Extension VPN plug-in that just passes every packet through unmodified to the main interface.